# Jython - Correct way of creating class instances & executing methods from Python class

Tags: java, python, jython

I have a Python file which contains a class. I need to create an instance of that class and be able to call methods in that through Java.

I came up with a solution like this:

```
    PythonInterpreter r = new PythonInterpreter();
    r.execfile("File.py");


    PyObject p = r.eval("Car().begin()");
    System.out.println(p.toString());
```

And the python code:

```
class Car(SomeExtendedClass):

    myvar = 5

    def set(self, my):
        self.myvar = my;

    def begin(self):
        return self.myvar
```

Now, when I execute this, it prints `5` But if I run the following code:

```
    PyObject p = r.eval("Car().begin()");
    System.out.println(p.toString());

    r.eval("Car().set(7)");

    p = r.eval("Car().begin()");

    System.out.println(p.toString());
```

It will still print `5`, instead of `7`

It looks like I did not create one instance of `Car` and it always creating a new instance instead of using the created one.

Am I right?

**Is it possible to create a new instance from a class in a Python file, and invoke/get data from methods with Java?**

I have tried loading `PyInstance` using `eval()` but I get cannot cast exception from it:

```
return (PyInstance) this.interpreter.eval(className);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call `Car()` you create a new instance of the class. So this create a new object and calls its set method:

```
r.eval("Car().set(7)");
```

But this then creates another instance rather than manipulating the existing one:

```
p = r.eval("Car().begin()");
```

The call to `r.eval("Car().begin()");` creates a new python object as you require, but it actually returns a reference to the python object containing the return value from the `begin()` method - not to the instance created. This isn't what you wanted.

Leaving the python class exactly as defined, this code gets a reference to a single instance of the class:

```
PyObject p = r.eval("Car()");
```

(As you already saw, an alternative is to omit the parenthesis which gets you a reference to the python class object, and then using `__call__` on it to create an instance).

Then to call the method on the existing instance:

```
p.invoke("set", Py.newInteger(7));
```

To get at the modified value, since it is an attribute of the instance and is not available via a 'getter' method, the **getattr** method of the PyObject class can get to it (or you could add a get method to the python code):

```
System.out.println(p.__getattr__("myvar"));
```

It's a shame that once you get a reference to the object via `p` you can't just call the method on it with java syntax, but of course Java knows nothing of the methods and/or attributes available on the Python object and even if it did they could change at any time because of the dynamic nature of Python. So you're left with methods like `invoke` to bind Java/Python together.

Answer (score 3):

I just found out the solution for this "mystery"

At first, we want to execute the python file we're going to get instances from:

```
r.execfile("File.py");
```

And then define the `PyObject` which will contain the class that you want to invoke:

```
PyObject car = r.get("Car");
```

And then you have to call the `__call__` method in order to create a new instance of `Car`, and **cast** it to `PyObjectDerived`:

```
PyObjectDerived p = (PyObjectDerived) o.__call__();
```

Now you can invoke methods, like this:

Python code:

```
def set(self, my):
    self.myvar = my;
```

Your java call:

```
p.invoke("set", Py.newInteger(5));
```

Hope I helped anyone.